# Firefox loads page in wrong tab

Tags: firefox

Probably since Firefox 18 *sometimes* the following happens:

1. I click at a link, which opens in the active tab
2. While the page starts loading (or maybe slightly before it starts), I switch to another tab
3. The page loads in this tab I switched to, not in the original tab where I clicked at it

This never happened to me before (I use FF since version 1.x).

Any ideas why this happening, and how I can prevent/fix it (besides waiting for a page to load until I switch to different tabs)?

EDIT: Maybe it plays a role that my Firefox is kind of slow (thanks to many open tabs, [many tab groups](https://superuser.com/q/498765/151741) and a huge history), so probably this can't be reproduced on a fresh (= fast) profile.

Comment: I would try and uninstall it completely and then download the latest version.

Comment: 18 versions later, Fx 36 still has this issue :|